# How to include only certain folders in lftp mirror?

Tags: ftp, lftp

I want to sync only some folders from an ftp with many folders.
Therefore, I'm trying first to exclude everything, and the only list the dirs I want to have explicit:

```
lftp mirror --exclude=.* --include=my/path/subdir1/* --include=my/path/subdir2/* $SOURCEFOLDER $TARGETFOLDER
```

Result: nothing gets synced. But why?

Comment: `--include` is regex, `/*` means `/` or `//` or `///` or ..., you get the point.

Comment: How does this answer my question why nothing is synced anymore if I include a `.../*` subdir wildpath in the `--inlude` option?

Comment: The point is that it doesn't include, that's why nothing is synced...
`/*` is not a wildcard path, it's a `slash` repeated 0 or more times. Try with `--include-glob=my/path/sub/*` or `--include=my/path/sub/.*`. See [docs](https://linux.die.net/man/1/lftp) and the difference between `RX` and `GP`.

Comment: Oh I see, thanx for that insight. Maybe you would like to add this as an answer?

Comment: Not confident that's the only problem, let me know if it works :)